# How to get price without a sign €/l?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-finance

I use this formula to get the data:

```
importXML("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; "//table[@class=('table')]//tr")
```

How to get price without a sign **€/l**?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTXML("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; 
 "//table[@class=('table')]//tr")\ INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; 
 "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"); " €/l"; "");;2)}; 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col3")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTXML("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; 
 "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"); "."; ","); 
 "\d+,\d+")*GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:EURUSD"); "0.00"); TRIM(
 IMPORTXML("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; 
 "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell me how you can hide a "Difference" column of data?

Comment: @TomashPrudków use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFNA(TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTXML("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; 
 "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"); "."; ","); 
 "\d+,\d+")*GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:EURUSD"); "0.00"); TRIM(
 IMPORTXML("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; 
 "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"))); 9^9; 2))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `substitute()` or `regexreplace()` with `iferror()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    iferror( 
      0.001 *
      value( 
        substitute( 
          importxml("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en", "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"), 
          " €/l", "" 
        ) 
      ), 
      0.001 * 
      importxml("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en", "//table[@class=('table')]//tr") 
    ), 
    importxml("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en", "//table[@class=('table')]//tr") 
  ) 
)
```

Or, depending on your locale, it may be:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    iferror( 
      0,001 *
      value( 
        substitute( 
          importxml("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; "//table[@class=('table')]//tr"); 
          " €/l"; "" 
        ) 
      ); 
      0,001 * 
      importxml("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; "//table[@class=('table')]//tr") 
    ); 
    importxml("https://at.fuelo.net/fuel/type/gasoline?lang=en"; "//table[@class=('table')]//tr") 
  ) 
)
```

The `0.001 *` bit and the outer `iferror()` are only required when your spreadsheet locale uses period as decimal mark.

Comment: Please indicate which **File > Settings > Locale** your spreadsheet is using. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.